# Abstract class cannot be initiated, then why be it allowed substitutable class to derived class?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have abstract class and normal class.  The normal class inherited from abstract class.

see below

```
public abstract class ABParent
{
    public void Add()
    {

    }
}

public class Derived : ABParent
{
    public void Show()
    {

    }
}
```

Here abstract class can't be instantiated. In other words, we can't create object for abstract class.

See below code

```
ABParent objABParent = new Derived();
```

From above code, `objABParent` is act like instance of abstract class and we can only access all elements in abstract class by using `objABParent`.

So my doubt is how it work as instance of abstract class?

Comment: Even though `objABParent` is declared as a `ABParent` it is still an instance of `Derived`. Just by casting like that it doesn't change the type of the instance. It just changes how you can interact with the object.

Comment: First of all syntax is incorrect, second `AbstractParent parent = new Child();` will work. _"From above code, objABParent is act like instance of abstract class and we can only access all elements in abstract class by using objABParent."_ Is that a statement or question? If statement, then false, `objABParent` is instance of `Derived` type.

Comment: In addition to @SᴇM's comment, you need to learn what really _polymorphism_ is in regardless of any OOP language..

Comment: OP, consider the same question but substituting "abstract [base] class" with "interface".

Comment: I think you should start here [abstract (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)   then this [Casting and type conversions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) then this [Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism)

Comment: Being able to use the derived class where only the base abstract class is needed is pretty much _the whole point_ of having an abstract class (likewise an interface). See marked duplicates. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle for important related discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to have a collection of objects that are not all `Derived`, but you just want `Add()` stuff in them, the way it is done in `ABParent`. now what you do is add them to a list of abstracts and then you can just foreach all of them:

```
List<ABParent> classesThatAdd()
        {
            new DerivedA(),
            new Derivedb(), 
            new Derived(), 
            new Derived()
        };

foreach (var item in classesThatAdd)
{
    item.Add(new object());
}
```

Not all derived classes (`DerivedA`, `DerivedB`) need to have `Show()`, but they all have `Add()`

Comment: if you are into games  an easier example might be a base abstract class- `Character`, that all characters derive from- a Warror, rogue, mage. they all have different stat values and different skills (maybe ) but they but they all `Fight(Character enemy)` the same way- they apply their `this.AtkSkill * this.Dmg` to `enemy.Health`

Answer (score 0):

Using the abstract modifier in a class declaration to indicate that a class is intended only to be a base class of other classes, not instantiated on its own. Members marked as abstract must be implemented by non-abstract classes that derive from the abstract class.
The abstract keyword enables you to create classes and class members that are incomplete and must be implemented in a derived class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members

If you want to create class member that must be implemented in a derived class, you can do something like this:

```
public abstract class ABParent
{
    public abstract void Add();
}

public class Derived : ABParent
{
    public void Add(){ }
    public void Show(){ }
}
```

In your case you can call method of base class, becuase this method was implemented in a base class.
You can use `virtual` method. When an abstract class inherits a virtual method from a base class, the abstract class can override the virtual method.